# Ejercicio librería Datetime

Tags: python

ya hice una pregunta sobre este ejercicio pero por formularla mal decidi crear otra, en este ejercicio tengo que crear un programa que me diga cuantos días falta para mi cumpleaños y el día de la semana que es.

```
import datetime

fecha_hoy = datetime.datetime.today()
dia_cumpleanos = int(input("¿Qué día cumples? "))
mes_cumpleanos = int(input("¿Qué mes cumples? "))
ano_estamos = int(input("¿En qué año estamos? "))

fecha_cumpleanos = datetime.datetime(day=dia_cumpleanos, month=mes_cumpleanos, year=ano_estamos)

resta_dias_cumple = fecha_hoy - fecha_cumpleanos

dia_semana_cumple = fecha_cumpleanos.weekday()
week_day_cumple = ""

if dia_semana_cumple == 0:
    week_day_cumple = "Lunes"
elif dia_semana_cumple == 1:
    week_day_cumple = "Martes"
elif dia_semana_cumple == 2:
    week_day_cumple = "Miércoles"
elif dia_semana_cumple == 3:
    week_day_cumple = "Jueves"
elif dia_semana_cumple == 4:
    week_day_cumple = "Viernes"
elif dia_semana_cumple == 5:
    week_day_cumple = "Sábado"
elif dia_semana_cumple == 6:
    week_day_cumple = "Domingo"

print("Faltan {} días para tu cumple, un {}".format(resta_dias_cumple.strftime("%d"), week_day_cumple))
```

La cosa es que en la última línea dice que no se puede ejecutar el strftime por que AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'strftime'. He estado tratando de poner los datos de resta_dias_cumple en otra variable datetime.datetime pero dice Unexpected type(s): timedelta.
No sé como hacer que el strftime funcione, espero haberme explicado bien.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno entre los detalles de la logica no me metere muy a fondo hice algunos cambios que segun yo pueden ayudarte a plantear una mejor forma de logica.

Debido a que restas dos fechas el objeto que te entrega es un datetime.timedelta y por esta razon no podes mostrarlo como un datetime normal. Te sugiero leer la documentacion en la misma da un ejemplo asi:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> d = timedelta(microseconds=-1)
>>> (d.days, d.seconds, d.microseconds)
(-1, 86399, 999999)
```

Eso fue sacado de https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html para que puedas revisarlo. En base a ese ejemplo realize las modificaciones en tu codigo

```
import datetime

fecha_hoy = datetime.datetime.today()
dia_cumpleanos = int(input("¿Qué día cumples? "))
mes_cumpleanos = int(input("¿Qué mes cumples? "))
ano_estamos = int(input("¿En qué anio estamos? "))

fecha_cumpleanos = datetime.datetime(day=dia_cumpleanos, month=mes_cumpleanos, year=ano_estamos+1)

resta_dias_cumple = fecha_cumpleanos - fecha_hoy

print(resta_dias_cumple)
dia_semana_cumple = fecha_cumpleanos.weekday()
print(dia_semana_cumple)
week_day_cumple = ""

if dia_semana_cumple == 0:
    week_day_cumple = "Lunes"
elif dia_semana_cumple == 1:
    week_day_cumple = "Martes"
elif dia_semana_cumple == 2:
    week_day_cumple = "Miércoles"
elif dia_semana_cumple == 3:
    week_day_cumple = "Jueves"
elif dia_semana_cumple == 4:
    week_day_cumple = "Viernes"
elif dia_semana_cumple == 5:
    week_day_cumple = "Sábado"
elif dia_semana_cumple == 6:
    week_day_cumple = "Domingo"

#print(resta_dias_cumple.days)
print("Faltan {} días para tu cumple, un {}".format(resta_dias_cumple.days, week_day_cumple))
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda amigo!, solo quería decir que el código me funciono sin sumarle 1 a ano_estamos, me extrañé un poco al verlo jajaja.